# How to Fix Wood Tabletop (Finish stripped off by bottom of bug spray can left on overnight)

Tags: finishing, tabletop

After leaving a bug spray can on my wooden table overnight, I went to remove it the following morning. When I did the wood seemed stuck to the bottom of the can. As I removed it, the finish was taken off. What is the best way to fix?

Comment: This would depend a lot on the finish. You can search the [tag:finish] and [tag:finishing] tags to look through the existing answers to find out how to test to see what your table was finished with, then [edit] that into your question. While you're searching, you will also find some very useful info on repairing whatever kind of finish you've got on _your_ table. If you don't find something specifically for your finish, [edit] your post to explain your particular situation and explain what's not working for you.

Comment: Note that some of the descriptions on testing the finish may be in the comments on the OP as well...

Comment: It's very likely you will need to strip and refinish. Not the whole piece, but the entire of the top surface at least. If it is finished in shellac or lacquer a spot repair is eminently possible as long as you already know how, but take it as a given that it's pretty much impossible for a first-timer to get a seamless result. So even with those finishes which are known for their easy repairability you are probably best off stripping and refinishing.